# Getting users email from facebook api or using socialauth-net

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using socialauth-net [Here](http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-net/) to allow users to log into my site. I get all the data back except the most important thing...Email. I have the user token and username, is there a way I can grab the email address as well? I set the User and Friends Permissions to allow email on facebook. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, just thought I'd answer it anyway.

I don't think your settings matter. It's whether or not your contacts allow their address to be visible and exported.

Could that be the case? Spreading email addresses these days is a very sensitive topic, and most providers avoid exposing them to third party applications.